# Javascript event between onFocus and onChange

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working a web page where I'd like to run some JavaScript code when a user alters text in a given input field, but I can't figure out which event to trap (assuming one exists) that would give me the behavior I'm looking for.  `onFocus` happens too soon -- if the user selects the field but doesn't change any text, I don't want anything to happen.  But `onChange` is too late -- I'd like the JavaScript to fire as soon as the user starts typing, not when the user is *done* typing and clicks something else.  How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onkeydown` (although it wouldn't work for pasted data, where `onchange` is probably better).

Comment: ... and extra thanks for the "onChange" caveat, I don't know that I would have caught that.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple events that can help you:

- **onKeydown** (fired when a key is pressed down)
- **onKeyup** (fired when a key is released)
- **onKeypress** (fired when a key is pressed and then released)

Comment: looks like i got beat to it... thats what I get wasting time formatting my answer :P

Comment: Yeah, the site does reward knowledge AND fast typing, doesn't it?  +1 for the effort, though, it is appreciated.

Comment: I consider it good form to wait at least an hour before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

keydown / keyup / keypress?

Comment: Thanks, but David beat you to it.  +1 for the effort, though, it is appreciated.